# Zend PDF mixes up Width and Height of a Page

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

I'm using Zend_Pdf, and at one point I am reading my source page's Width and Height using `$page->getWidth();` and `$page->getHeight();`

Most of the time it reads fine.

Sometimes, however, Zend PDF returns are the opposite - it shows 11in as width and 8.5in as height for a standard Letter-sized PDF. I can't figure out why it would do that.

I tried saving the PDF in question as 1.4, as PDF/A, but the result is all the same.

Comment: Possibly Landscape vs Portrait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of investigation I was able to figure it out.

Turns out the page was coded as having "Rotate" set to 270 degrees.

You can access this variable inside Zend_Pdf_Page:

```
$this->_pageDictionary->Rotate->value
```

Then if Rotate is set to 90 or 270, I reverse Width and Height.